# Install a 3rd-party dependency with maven before dependencies are resolved

Tags: maven

I would like to deploy a maven project that depends on a 3rd-party jar, located in a "lib/" directory that is distributed with my project source.

The usual way to do this (as explained [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296380/maven-installing-3rd-party-jar-file) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184724/add-3rd-party-jars-with-maven-package) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470611/maven-unable-to-install-3rd-party-jar)) is to have the user install the jar into a local maven repository before building the project, by typing a command such as `mvn install:install-file` at the shell.

This manual solution won't do for deployment, however (because requiring users to manually install dependencies is *so 1998...*).  So I thought I'd specify an `install-file` goal in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.my.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

...

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5.2</version>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>install-jar-lib</id>
    <phase>validate</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>install-file</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <groupId>edu.my.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <file>${project.basedir}/lib/myartifact.jar</file>
      <generatePom>true</generatePom>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

The problem is that maven attempts to resolve dependencies before `install-file` runs, even when I specify it to run as early as the `validate` phase.  It thus complains that it cannot find the dependency.

This question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951999/is-there-are-way-to-install-maven-dependencies-before-maven-attempts-to-resolve) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618192/install-local-jar-dependency-as-part-of-the-lifecycle-before-maven-attempts-to), and a few unpleasantly complicated solutions have been offered such as these:

1. Run `maven-install-plugin` during the `clean` phase and require users to run `mvn clean` before building the artifact.
2. Set up multiple modules, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951999/is-there-are-way-to-install-maven-dependencies-before-maven-attempts-to-resolve).
3. Use `<systemPath>` to load the jar as a system library. (This doesn't meet my requirements, because I am using `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy dependency jars into the deployed application directory, which ignores system libraries.)
4. Write a custom plugin.

None of these satisfy me.  This seems like a routine task any build system encounters. There must be a simpler way to install dependencies with maven.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was to use *both* `install-file` *and* `<systemPath>`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.my.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/myartifact.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

...

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5.2</version>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>install-jar-lib</id>
    <phase>validate</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>install-file</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <groupId>edu.my.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <file>${project.basedir}/lib/myartifact.jar</file>
      <generatePom>true</generatePom>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

This way, when Maven compiles the project, it resolves the 3rd-party dependency as a system library.  But it also installs the library into the local maven repository, so that `maven-dependency-plugin`'s `copy-dependencies` goal is able to find it.